# the string "Container not found." was thrown, throw an Error :) during mocha sigma angular directive testing

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, chai, sigma.js, linkurious

i am trying to write unit test for sigma angular directive but i am getting this error. `the string "Container not found." was thrown, throw an Error :)`

Source code

```
 angular
    .module('test')
    .directive('sigmagraph', directive);

function directive() {

        var divId = 'sigma-container-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999999);
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<div id="' + divId + '" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" class="sigmaContainer">' +
                      '</div>',
            scope: {
                graph: '=',
                isVisible: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                // Create a sigma instance.
                var sigmaInstance = new sigma({
                    settings: _newSigmaSettings,
                    renderer: {
                        container: divId,
                        type: 'canvas'
                    }
                });
               //other code..
            }
        }
    }
```

Test code

```
describe('sigmagraph', function() {
var scope,element;
beforeEach(function () {
    module('ui.router');
    module('tresata.orion');
    module('core');


    inject(function  ($compile, $rootScope, $templateCache) {
        // $templateCache.put('<div class="sigmaContainer"></div>'); // also tried this but its not working 
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = angular.element('<sigmagraph graph="graph" is-visible="view.graphView">');
        scope.graph = mockGraphData;
        $compile(element)(scope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
    });
});

it('should apply template', function() {
    expect(element.html()).to.not.be.empty;
});
```

i also tried to solve this problem using $templateCache but still its not working. I'm beginner in testing so may be i missed something. please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved a problem just the same as yours.

Because your directive has a link function which will be executed after compiling, and at this time, there's no element appended on the DOM.

So if you use the `$compile` service to compile your directive dynamically, you'b better append your element of directive before compile it. Modify the code like below may help you:

```
inject(function  ($compile, $rootScope, $templateCache) {
    // $templateCache.put('<div class="sigmaContainer"></div>'); // also tried this but its not working 
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.graph = mockGraphData;
    element = angular.element('<sigmagraph graph="graph" is-visible="view.graphView">');
    angular.element('body').append(element);
    $compile(element)(scope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
});
```